# App rejected cause minimum functions

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I submitted a Real Estate App (Category: Business, secondary: Shopping)

My app include:

- Sign up/Sign in to be a user.
- Create product and post it to the server. (I use CloudKit)
- Save products that user like.
- Call to another (seller, requester ...), share to FaceBook (or Twitter ... - UIActivityController)

But Apple rejects it cause Minimum Functions:

> "We noticed that your app’s main functionality is to market your
> service, with limited or no user-facing interactive features or
> functionality. Apps that are primarily marketing materials or
> advertisements are not appropriate for the App Store. We encourage you
> to review your app concept and incorporate different content and
> features that are in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We understand that there are no hard and fast rules to define useful
> or entertaining, but Apple and Apple customers expect apps to provide
> a really great user experience. Apps should provide valuable utility
> or entertainment, draw people in by offering compelling capabilities
> or content, or enable people to do something they couldn't do before
> or in a way they couldn't do it before."

I read App Store Review Guidelines but I think that my App has the user experience, cause I free for everyone to post their topic to my app server. So anyone can access to their topic and call or share or email or send the message to each other.

But it's rejected.

What can I do now?

Comment: check your app where doesn't meet App store condition

Comment: If you feel that it having the experience according to guideline, schedule a call with apple guys and you can explain him on call. If its fine he will approve otherwise he will explain you where you are lacking for UX.

Comment: Reply to Hoàng Đăng: I tested flight it already. It run OK. No Crash.

Comment: Reply to Moin Shirazi: in the past, I replied Apple for me to contact to technical engineer (to explain for another app) but they did not gave me anything. So, how can I get them for a call?

Answer (score 2):

Login to your iTunes account. Where you are viewing the error or apple rejection message there is an option "Reply Submit an appeal to the App Review Board", after selecting that option you will have some more option, selects the one which you find suitable and contact the apple review team. Schedule a call with apple review team and you can explain them on call about you application functionality, if they find it OK they will approve else they will explain you lackings.

Comment: Unfortunately this linking feature for the support team is only available in some countries.

Answer (score 0):

Your app provides a limited user experience as it is not sufficiently different from a mobile browsing experience. As such, the experience it provides is similar to the general experience of using Safari. Including iOS features such as push notifications, Core Location, and sharing do not provide a robust enough experience to be appropriate for the App Store.